# Filtering specific data points from a dataframe based on a given conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like below

```
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   Date   | Loc 1 | Loc 2 | Loc 3 | Loc 4 | Loc 5 |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1-Jan-19 |    50 |     0 |    40 |    80 |    60 |
| 2-Jan-19 |    60 |    80 |    60 |    80 |    90 |
| 3-Jan-19 |    80 |    20 |     0 |    50 |    30 |
| 4-Jan-19 |    90 |    20 |    10 |    90 |    20 |
| 5-Jan-19 |    80 |     0 |    10 |    10 |     0 |
| 6-Jan-19 |   100 |    90 |   100 |     0 |    10 |
| 7-Jan-19 |    20 |    10 |    30 |    20 |     0 |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to extract all the data points (row label & column Label) if the value is zero and produce a new dataframe.

my desired output is as below

```
+--------------+----------------+
| Missing Date | Missing column |
+--------------+----------------+
| 1-Jan-19     | Loc 2          |
| 3-Jan-19     | Loc 3          |
| 5-Jan-19     | Loc 2          |
| 5-Jan-19     | Loc 5          |
| 6-Jan-19     | Loc 4          |
| 7-Jan-19     | Loc 5          |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Note on `5-Jan-19`, there are two entries `Loc 2` & `Loc 5`.

I know how to do this in Excel VBA. But, I'm looking for a more scalable solution with `python-pandas`.

so far i have attempted with the below code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Missing Date','Missing Column'])

for c in df.columns:
    if c != 'Date':
        if df[df[c] == 0]:
            new_df.append(df[c].index, c)
```

I'm new to pandas. Hence, guide me how to solve this issue.

Comment: and your attempts are?

Comment: updated with my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `melt` + `query`

```
(df.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='Missing column')
   .query('value == 0')
   .drop(columns='value')
)
```

---

```
        Date Missing column
7   1-Jan-19          Loc 2
11  5-Jan-19          Loc 2
16  3-Jan-19          Loc 3
26  6-Jan-19          Loc 4
32  5-Jan-19          Loc 5
34  7-Jan-19          Loc 5
```

Comment: Although I managed to solve it by myself (check the answer above), I'm compelled to accept your code. Elegant & loved it.!

Answer (score 4):

Melt the dateframe using the date column as `id_vars`, then filter where the value is zero (e.g. using `.loc[lambda x: x['value'] == 0]`).  Now it is just clean-up:

- sort values on `Date` and `Missing column`
- drop the `value` column (they all contain zeros)
- rename `Date` to `Missing Date`
- reset the index, dropping the original

.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('2019-1-1', '2019-1-7'),
    'Loc 1': [50, 60, 80, 90, 80, 100, 20],
    'Loc 2': [0, 80, 20, 20, 0, 90, 10],
    'Loc 3': [40, 60, 0, 10, 10, 100, 30],
    'Loc 4': [80, 80, 50, 90, 10, 0, 20],
    'Loc 5': [60, 90, 30, 20, 0, 10, 0],
})

df2 = (
    df
    .melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='Missing column')
    .loc[lambda x: x['value'] == 0]
    .sort_values(['Date', 'Missing column'])
    .drop('value', axis='columns')
    .rename({'Date': 'Missing Date'})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
>>> df2
        Date Missing column
0 2019-01-01          Loc 2
1 2019-01-03          Loc 3
2 2019-01-05          Loc 2
3 2019-01-05          Loc 5
4 2019-01-06          Loc 4
5 2019-01-07          Loc 5
```

Comment: Thank you. upvoted your answer. your code is similar to @ALollz answer. but, I loved it. learnt a new method `melt`,  btw, i managed to answer by myself. check the code above & give me your comments to further improve.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the crazy answer,

You can use for the dates :

```py
new_dates = pd.np.repeat(df.index, df.eq(0).sum(axis=1).values)
```

Replace `df.index` with `df['Date']` if necessary.

---

And for the values

```py
cols = pd.np.where(df.eq(0), df.columns, pd.np.NaN) 
new_cols = cols[pd.notnull(cols)]
```

Finally,

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_cols, index=new_dates, columns =['Missing column'])
```

alternatively you can create a new column instead of an index.

Now how does that work ?

`new_dates` takes the series and repeat each value as many times as their are `True` values in that row. I summed the `True` values over eachrow since they are equal to 1. Meaning, True when `df.eq(0)`.

Next, I call a filter that gives the column name if the value is zero, NaN otherwise.

Finally, we only get the non NaN values and put them in an array which we end up using to build your answer.

N.B : I used that toy data as example :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A":pd.np.random.randint(0,3,20),                                                               
        "B":pd.np.random.randint(0,3,20),
        "C":pd.np.random.randint(0,3,20), 
        "D":pd.np.random.randint(0,3,20)
    }, 
    index = pd.date_range("2019-01-01", periods=20, freq="D")
)
```

Comment: Thank you & upvoted . yes. your answer is also unique. I learnt a lot today. and I managed to solve it by myself. check my code above as well (very lame but i'm proud :)... thanks for the detailed answer)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this with `iterrows()`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

cols = ['Missing Date','Missing Column']
data_points = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for c in df.columns:
        if row[c] == 0:
            data_points.append([row['Date'],c])

df_final = pd.DataFrame(df_final = pd.DataFrame(data_points, columns=cols), columns=cols)
```

Comment: great question, however your answer is not 'pythonian' per-se. check ALollz answer. The tools he's using are the right tools for this job.

Comment: yes. I accepted his answer. But, I feel proud to having solved it by myself, being a new bee in python-pandas.

Comment: `iterrows` will be a very slow solution for larger datasets and should be avoided.

Comment: @Alexander OK. well noted.

Comment: @Alexander @adhg . Yes you are right. one of my other codes with `iterrows()` is very slow. Hence, I asked a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629485/speeding-up-pandas-code-by-replacing-iterrows). need your help once again.